# How to split a pandas column of type dict in columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. One of the columns of the dataframe is a `dict` object. The following dataframe is a toy example of the real dataframe:

```
 DF = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 'col1':[{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':5}, {'a':None, 'b':5, 'c':6}]})
```

I would like to split the `col1` in columns: one column per dictionary key. 
All the rows have the same keys.

After the splitting the dataframe should look like:

```
id  a   b    c
1    1  2    3
2   3   4    5
3  None  5   6
```

*NOTE*: I got the `dict` column from a `jsonb` column in postgresql.

Comment: Check if `pandas.DataFrame.from_records()` function works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 'col1':[{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':5}, {'a':None, 'b':5, 'c':6}]})
df.set_index('id').col1.apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
      a    b    c
id
1   1.0  2.0  3.0
2   3.0  4.0  5.0
3   NaN  5.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(DF['col1'].tolist())
df['id']=DF['id']
```

Then now:

```
print(df)
```

IS:

```
     a  b  c  id
0  1.0  2  3   1
1  3.0  4  5   2
2  NaN  5  6   3
```

Do:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(DF['col1'].tolist())
df.insert(0,'id',DF['id'])
print(df)
```

For putting `'id'` at front

Output:

```
   id    a  b  c
0   1  1.0  2  3
1   2  3.0  4  5
2   3  NaN  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
df = pd.concat([DF.drop(['col1'], axis=1), DF['col1'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

**output**

```
    id  a     b     c
0   1   1.0   2.0   3.0
1   2   3.0   4.0   5.0
2   3   NaN   5.0   6.0
```