# How to transform values from dataframe(python) attributes from a row into columns?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe [Current Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey1At.png) loaded from a csv, that I want to use do some sampling tests.

For that I wanted to use all of the current columns, but trying to transform Element_Count and Tag_Count into separate columns from the values from Element_Count(e.g link: 10) and Tag_Count(separately).

I want to extract each value and turn it into a column. The final dataframe would be something like this(obviously depending on the values inside of Element/Tag_Count) :

Index (the 0,1,2 etc from the dataframe its self) PageID ,Uri, A, AA, AAA, link (and its value inside of Element_Count, e.g link as column and in the case of the first one in the picture 44 in the row for that specific url) etc, html, etc (with all the values of Tag_Count present in all of the content inside of the rows of the column Tag_Count as explained for Element_Count)

The current code to generate the dataframe is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") #to ignore some warnings which have no effect in this particular case.

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
df.head()
```

I have searched google, also in here for some answers to no avail.

Have tried changing the test csv to achieve my goal, with no success. Have also tried after seeing a question on here to use:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.ranges.str.split(',').tolist())
```

to achieve the desired result with no success.

Any ideas in how to achieve this via dataframes, or by any other method?

(Anything that I have forgot to mention that u feel is important to understand the problem please say and I will edit it in)

**Edit :**

Although logic would say that the element and tag count arrays should be in dictionary form and easily dividable, that is not the case as shown in the [print](https://gyazo.com/f80618ff825287e39b6ab776ffda5413)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52548568/1342355 Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the redirect! It is close to what I wanted but in that question the input has the input of the column as a dictionary, which here is not the case, its an array for each value. Although that is the case, tried it out. Sadly didn't work out. Thank u for the redirect even if it didn't work for this case :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey1At.png > ElementCount is in dict format with curly braces. Please recheck.

Comment: After some rechecking still doesnt work, and after doing a print I soon discovered that he is not in a dictionary shape as shown here -> https://gyazo.com/f80618ff825287e39b6ab776ffda5413 Which in its self is weird, I agree... but that explains why the redirect didnt work...