# Create new column using keys pair value from a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame with many column. One of the column is named 'attributes' and in it has a list of dictionary with keys and values. I want to extract each keys and it values to it own column. [This is what the data frame look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEApz.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a pandas column of type dict in columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548448/how-to-split-a-pandas-column-of-type-dict-in-columns)

Answer (score 1):

The following will add the dictionary keys as additional columns, keeping the `attributes` column in the dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df["attributes"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

## Edit

For the nested dictionaries, trying this simple example worked for me (here the initial column of dictionaries is `colC`, with the nested dictionaries in `foo`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'colA': {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 5},
        'colB': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 10, 3: 2, 4: 5},
        'colC': {
            0: {'foo': {"A": 5, "B": 6, "C": 9}, 'bar': 182, 'baz': 148},
            1: {'bar': 103, 'baz': 155},
            2: {'foo': 165, 'bar': 184, 'baz': 170},
            3: {'foo': 121, 'bar': 151, 'baz': 187},
            4: {'foo': 137, 'bar': 199, 'baz': 108},
        },
    }
)

df = pd.concat([df, df["colC"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
#   colA  colB                                                       colC                       foo    bar    baz
#0     7     7  {'foo': {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}, 'bar': 182, 'baz': 148}  {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}  182.0  148.0
#1     2     8                                   {'bar': 103, 'baz': 155}                       NaN  103.0  155.0
#2     5    10                       {'foo': 165, 'bar': 184, 'baz': 170}                       165  184.0  170.0
#3     3     2                       {'foo': 121, 'bar': 151, 'baz': 187}                       121  151.0  187.0
#4     5     5                       {'foo': 137, 'bar': 199, 'baz': 108}                       137  199.0  108.0

df = pd.concat([df, df["foo"].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
#   colA  colB                                                       colC                       foo    bar    baz      0    A    B    C
#0     7     7  {'foo': {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}, 'bar': 182, 'baz': 148}  {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}  182.0  148.0    NaN  5.0  6.0  9.0
#1     2     8                                   {'bar': 103, 'baz': 155}                       NaN  103.0  155.0    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
#2     5    10                       {'foo': 165, 'bar': 184, 'baz': 170}                       165  184.0  170.0  165.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
#3     3     2                       {'foo': 121, 'bar': 151, 'baz': 187}                       121  151.0  187.0  121.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
#4     5     5                       {'foo': 137, 'bar': 199, 'baz': 108}                       137  199.0  108.0  137.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

There is the column `0` which appears because of the "empty" rows, but this should not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, its work. However I notice that it's nested dictionary.  And I try to reused the code on the new column but it didn't work. Any idea for a solution?

Comment: I don't know why this wouldn't work.  Are you able to share the code you tried and the error message that appeared?

Comment: there's no error message, It just add another exact column and didn't break it out.

Comment: I think I know why the code doesn't work. When I tried to reused the first code, it doesn't work because there are empty row. Any suggestion on how to do it on the nested dictionary?

Comment: I have added to my answer to give an example of how this should work (and the output that you should have).  Without you sharing your code I can't recreate the problem you are experiencing, as this works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have one more quick question if you can help me with. I have a Wifi column and the value is  u'free' and  u'no'. Is there way to convert it to 1 and 0?

Comment: You can use pandas [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) using something like this: `df["Wifi"] = df["Wifi"].map({u'free': 1, u'no': 0})`.  You will receive `nan` if the value is neither.